# Can Fiddler show wrong information?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, fiddler, wcf-rest

How could Fiddler show info which is different from what I see in debugger?

I have *HelloWorld* RESTful service on server side. When I called it from browser, everything is OK.
[image]

I can see this in Fiddler.
[image]

But then I tried to call this service from javascript with *jquery.ajax* method and something goes wrong.
[image]

Status is "error" and second parameter is not very descriptive.
[image]

At first I thought that something wrong with cross domain request, but then I saw in Fiddler that everything was OK with this request/response.
[image]

Why is that?

Comment: No, Fiddler can't lie to you (unless you tell it to). It's a faithful representation of what's going out over the wire.

Comment: @EricLaw I understand that. Basically what I'm asking is why I have different results from fiddler and firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the JavaScript console. You probably have a JS error there.

You say that this is a cross-domain request. The problem is mostly likely that you are blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The HTTP request and response worked fine, but the browser is denying JavaScript access to the data for security reasons.

You need to modify the server so it [gives permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) to read data to JavaScript on your site.

Comment: Yep, `Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` did the trick